# CSS gets messy on Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, frontend

My website looks good on Chrome but somehow looks messy on Safari, I don't know why, I'm using Safari 14.

Here's the code:
Https://github.com/halamh/nft-preview-card

And the website:
Https://halamh.github.io/nft-preview-card/

Comment: Please put enough code direct into your question to show the problem: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work in Safari.  You need to remove

```
display: flex;
```

from .main-container and then for img remove

```
min-width: 50%;
```

and replace with

```
max-width: 100%;
```

See screenshots from Safari below.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOvC0.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCILg.jpg)

Comment: Thank you so much! Although if I remove the flex from main, the container will go to the left for some reason

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear....Don't remove `display: flex;` from `<main>`, only remove it from your declaration for `.main-container` as you use in`<section class='main-container'>` and that should keep it centered.

Comment: Ok I did! Thank you!

Comment: :) Glad it worked!